# Display custom post type in author archive thanks to elementor

Tags: archive, author, elementor

I'm using Elementor Pro and its "Hello Theme" to build my website. I registered a CPT "movie" in fucntions.php. 
Now, I would like to display the archive from this new CPT on my author page but that doesn't seem to work : Elementor says it doesn't find any archive.
I tried adding this piece of code :

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'post_types_author_archives' );

function post_types_author_archives( $query ) {


    if ( $query->is_author ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'movie' ) );
    remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'post_types_author_archives' );
}`
```

Unfortunately, it didn't work neither...